# How to make a Drawn Line on a Form Invisible in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make an analog clock, wherein I would like to make my 'seconds' Line Invisible when the Seconds Changes. I have tried to set the Pen mode to `pmNotCopy` but it only gives Inverse of Pen Color. What Property must be set in this `Form1.Canvas.Pen.Mode:=<Blank>` so that My Line Disappears?

Any other Ideas are also appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about delphi but just some out if the box thinking:
couldn't you change the color of your line to the background color, making it 'invisible'

Comment: If the background is solid colour, that is.

Comment: @andreas : Can you tell me how to get the Main Form's BackGround color then?

Comment: That's simply `Color`, that is, the `Color` property of the form. If you are in any method of a form, you can simply write `Color` to access it. If you are inside a `with` and there is some other `Color` with higher priority, you can always obtain the form's `Color` property by writing `Self.Color`.

Comment: I did `Form1.Canvas.Pen.Color:=Form1.Color`;

Comment: @CyprUS: Don't do that (reference the `Form1` variable inside the form's methods or events. Use `Self` instead. See my note in my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Modern computers are very fast. If I were you, I'd definitely draw the entire clock from scratch every second. Problem solved. In addition, if you need anti-aliasing, then a simple pen mode trick will never work.

(If you are not using a remote desktop, you might want to employ double-buffering.)

Comment: :That will not be optimized code. Rather it sounds like a shortcut to the solution.

Comment: @CyprUS: Well, I agree it would have been problematic back in the Windows 3.1 days. (Then things like anti-aliasing, which are standard today, were totally 'science fiction'.)

Comment: You could keep an off-screen, in-memory bitmap of your clock "clean" without hands and when the display needs to be updated you could make a temporary copy of that bitmap, draw the hands on it still in memory then blit the final result to screen and discard the temporary copy. That should be fast enough. You could also optimize by clipping to a minimum region that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

You were close. You need to use `pmXOR`.

Try this:

Create a new Delphi VCL Forms application. Drop a TButton on the bottom of the form (Button1). 
Add the code below to the Button1Click event.

Run the application. Click the button, and three parallel lines will be drawn across the top. Click the button again, and the three lines will disappear.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmXor;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clGreen;
  for i := 1 to 3 do
  begin
    Canvas.MoveTo(50, i * 20);
    Canvas.LineTo(Width - 50, i * 20);
  end;
end;
```

All drawing should normally be done in the OnPaint event; I'm intentionally drawing in the Button1Click event for demonstration reasons only.

Just as a note: You should never use `Form1` inside an event handler for that form. Referencing the `Form1` variable prevents you from creating more than one instance of the form. Use `Self` instead, and that will automatically refer to the instance the code is running in.